# Creating RegEx from other RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I really like Regular Expressions. I was wondering if this kind of things can be done in JavaScript.

Imagine that you want to match the words *foo* and *bar*, but only when they are followed by "?" Or "!". I know that this simple case could be done with `x(?=y)`, but my intention here is to know if you can place one RegEx inside another, as it would be great for more difficult scenarios.

I mean something like this:

```
var regex1 = /foo|bar/;
var regex2 = /{regex1}[\?\!]/;
```

This would simplify very complex regexes and would make some patters reusable without having to write the same patterns every time you need it. It would be something like a *RegEx variable*, if that makes sense.

Is it possible?

Comment: Use `RegExp` constructor notation, see [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RegExp` constructor.

```
new RegExp('(?:' + regex1.source + ')[?!]')
```

[`regex1.source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) will give the actual regex as string without the delimiters and flags which then can be passed to the `RegExp` constructor to create new regex.

Also, note that there is no need to escape `?` and `!` when used inside character class.

```js
var regex1 = /foo|bar/;
var regex = new RegExp('(?:' + regex1.source + ')[?!]')
console.log(regex);
```

Comment: I think OP uses `{}` as in C# 6.0 interpolated strings. `new RegExp('(?:' + regex1.source + ')[?!]')` is necessary then.